# Custom deleter for boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a question regarding providing a custom delete-method to `boost::shared_ptr` constructor.

For example, I have a `GameObjectFactory` class which creates/destroys `GameObjects`. It has an instance of a `MemoryManager`, which can `Allocate()/Deallocate()` memory. `CreateObject()` returns a `GameObject`, allocated through the `MemoryManager`, encapsulated in a `boost::shared_ptr`.

When the `boost::shared_ptr` destructs, it should call my `MemoryManager->Deallocate()` method. However I can't get it right; I get these errors:

```
error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
error C2661: 'boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

I have read the boost documentation and the hits I got from stackoverflow, yet I cannot get it right. I dont understand why the below dosnt work.

Here's my code;

```
#ifndef _I_GAMEOBJECT_MANAGER_H
#define _I_GAMEOBJECT_MANAGER_H

#include "../../Thirdparty/boost_1_49_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp"

#include "EngineDefs.h"
#include "IMemoryManager.h"
#include "../Include/Core/GameObject/GameObject.h"

namespace Engine
{
    class IGameObjectFactory
    {
    public:
        virtual ~IGameObjectFactory() { }

        virtual int32_t Init() = 0;
        virtual bool Destroy() = 0;
        virtual bool Start() = 0;
        virtual bool Stop() = 0;
        virtual bool isRunning() = 0;
        virtual void Tick() = 0;

        template <class T>
        inline boost::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject()
        {
            boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr((T*) mMemoryMgr->Allocate(sizeof(T)),&mMemoryMgr->Deallocate);


            return ptr;
        }

        template <class T>
        inline boost::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(bool UseMemoryPool)
        {
            boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr((T*) mMemoryMgr->Allocate(sizeof(T),UseMemoryPool), &mMemoryMgr->Deallocate);


            return ptr;
        }

    protected:
        IMemoryManager* mMemoryMgr;
    };

}

#endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`shared_ptr` expects the deleter to be a function that accepts a single argument that is the pointer type (`T*`). You are trying to pass it a member function, and since `shared_ptr` has no reference to the IMemoryManager object, it won't work. To get around this, create a static member function that accepts the pointer object and calls IMemoryManager::Deallocate() :

```
template <class T>
static void Deallocate(T* factoryObject)
{
    factoryObject->mMemoryMgr->Deallocate();
}
```

You can then create your shared_ptr like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr((T*) mMemoryMgr->Allocate(sizeof(T),UseMemoryPool), &IGameObjectFactory::Deallocate<T>);
```

Comment: I still get the following error: error C2661: 'boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments      Using the latest boost build

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Well, what version of Boost are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), as well as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) takes a predicate as a custom deleter. So you can pass a function, or a functor. What you are passing is a pointer to a member function, which is not enough to invoke it since you don't have a pointer to an object. You have to study [Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) for details. There are many ways to achieve what you want, I'd write my own simple functor that remembers an object factory pointer, and calls an appropriate method to delete it once invoked by the `shared_ptr`. Also, consider using `intrusive_ptr` unless you really need `shared_ptr`. It is a lot more efficient.